# Nginx: How to escape argument value for proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

We have such a location configuration:

```
location ~ ^/suggest/(?<search>.+) {
    proxy_pass https://internal.host/v1/products?suggest=$search;
}
```

The problem is that `internal.host` receives `$search` as is, which means that anyone from the outside can pass `&another_param=value` as a value of `$search` and thus gain unauthorized access to the remote endpoint.

The question is: how to escape the argument value?

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ ^/app/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass       http://192.169.154.102:9999/some_dir/$1;
}
```

This examples results in:

```
test.com/app/request/xxxxx => http://192.168.154.102:9999/some_dir/xxxxx
```

Not that the example needs to be adjusted to fit your needs.
Please review [this link](https://www.liaohuqiu.net/posts/nginx-proxy-pass/) for more information on proxy_pass(ing) with arguments. Additionally your web application/script that takes in the arguments should perform a check on the parameters given. **Before** anything is done with the parameters, perform checks and/or filtering of the parameter passed! Please also do some checks, if the above method does limit the parameter, which it should - but please check.

Example from: [Nginx proxy_pass: examples for how does nginx proxy_pass map the request](https://www.liaohuqiu.net/posts/nginx-proxy-pass/).

Comment: Sorry, I think, you misunderstood the question. 1. I need to pass that as an argument value, not as a path. 2. I need to have it url_escaped before passed, otherwise it can be possible to pass unescaped ampersand and thus pass arbitrary arguments. And as you can understand, it has nothing to do with the validation in the application that accepts the request.